# MySQL & Socket.IO – Flooding Database > Duplikate transactions

Tags: mysql, node.js, sockets, spam-prevention

I don't know exactly where I should post my problem and the question behind it, but I'll give it a try here.

Some time ago I had a small project where users were able to spent coins on thinks. These coins were stored as balance on their user account in my MySQL database. The frontend was connected to the backend using `socket.io` and the node app communicated with the database using the regular `mysql` module.

​

**The problem:**
Unfortunately, after a while I found out that it was possible to flood / spam the node app using the [socket.io](https://socket.io) connection (or open up the website multiple times to get the same result) in order to slow down the mysql querys. That's why it was possible to spent the coins a user had twice or more.

The normal workflow was like:

```
Request to DB
check balance
if balance > 0
    spend coins
        reduce coins in DB
else
    reject
```

Request end

How to spent coins twice: (**the problem**)

```
Request to DB
Request to DB
    check balance
    check balance
    if balance > 0
    if balance > 0
        spend coins
        spend coins
        reduce coins in DB
        reduce coins in DB
    else
        reject
Request end
Request end
```

By that it was possible to reach the code to spent the coins BEFORE the balance were updated.

​

**Question:**
How is it possible to prevent users from doing such things? Using a request limiter only works for people using the same IP so scriptkiddys should not be able to reach something I mentioned above. What about people using a small botnet with different ip's?

​

If I ever get a solution for that problem I could start the project again.

Comment: don't your users have user accounts? Otherwise how do you know who they are? You can rate-limit individual users (as well as IPs - or maybe even some combination of the two, if you spot the same user accounts coming from the same group of IPs)

Comment: yes, my users have account but its still possible to flood the DB without an account. For example: sending get requests using the socket connection for data which someone has to get without an account and when the database slows down make the transaction with an account which is logged in.

Comment: I see. if a simple heavy load is causing you data integrity issues I'd say you've got some issues in your code and/or application architecture - maybe try to look at that, rather than fight bots. In a financial system the requests to update a balance should be queued in the order they're received and then processed in the correct order. It shouldn't be possible to cause the system to process the requests out of sequence, especially not with a simple DDOS attack.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `select for update ... where user = XXX` to lock in the `check balance`.

Another solution is to add a `version` column. then `get balance and version`, (let's assume verison is n), `spend`, `reduce coins and set version= n+1  where version == n`, then the later fill fail. in this solution, you should `spend coins` after a `reduce succeeded.`.

These are only general solutions as only as a reference because I am not familiar with socket.io.

Comment: looks like a good solution! I'll try this out in the future. BTW: Socket.IO is just for communicating in realtime with the backend.